Authorization Failure for CDN Purge Action in Azure CLI Script
I am trying to automate my workflow through giyhub actions but it shows the following error
Run azure/CLI@v1
Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.58.0
ERROR: (AuthorizationFailed) The client '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' with object id '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action' over scope '/subscriptions/bf94b8dd-32e1-4d61-ac66-992080104192/resourceGroups/cloudresume/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/azureresumenkg/endpoints/azureresumenkg' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
Code: AuthorizationFailed
Message: The client '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' with object id '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action' over scope '/subscriptions/bf94b8dd-32e1-4d61-ac66-992080104192/resourceGroups/cloudresume/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/azureresumenkg/endpoints/azureresumenkg' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
Error: Error: az cli script failed.
cleaning up container...
MICROSOFT_AZURE_CLI_1711863820587_CONTAINER

Error: az cli script failed.

its purpose was to automatically purge the contents of azure endpoint.enter image description here


Message: The client '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' with object id '1b577114-b48e-4f1d-aaa7-99e39635f911' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action' over scope '/subscriptions/bf94b8dd-32e1-4d61-ac66992080104192/resourceGroups/cloudresume/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/azureesumenkg/endpoints/azureresumenkg' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The above error occurs if your service principal does not have the required roles or permissions to perform the operation.
To resolve the error, make sure to assign the CDN Endpoint Contributor role to the service principal at the required scope, as it has this permission in it Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action.
First, I assigned the role to the service principal in the portal.
Portal:

Here, I used a sample API to purge the Azure CDN cache. After assigning the role, I ran the API call below by generating an access token again and got a successful response like this:
Request
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/venkatuser/endpoints/venkat123/purge?api-version=2023-05-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
  "contentPaths": [
    "/folder1"
  ]
}

Output:

Reference:
Endpoints - Purge Content - REST API (Azure CDN) | Microsoft Learn
